# innerHTML, DOM elements, background color, style

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, innerhtml

I am adding rows to a table through DOM elements and innerHTML. It works, only problem is cell3. The background color won't show. I believe it's because cell3 has an appended element. Help?

```
        var table = document.getElementById("vessel_tab");

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow();
        //row.style.backgroundColor="#7F9EBE"; doesn't work as bg for entire row

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.style.backgroundColor="#7F9EBE"; working  

        cell1.innerHTML = "<font color='#000'><strong>EMS 345</strong></font>";
        cell1.colSpan = 2;

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell3.style.backgroundColor="#7F9EBE"; !NOT WORKING

        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        cell3.innerHTML = "<img title='remove'  src='images/delete-row-icon1.png' class='sub_icon remove'/> &nbsp;";
        cell3.appendChild(element1);
```

Comment: Are you sure `row.insertCell(1)` correct returns an element in which you can apply a background color to? Have you tried the `cssText` property to set `background-color: "7F9EBE"` as an alternative?

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/C2QKa/). I changed the color of the cell1 cell so that the difference is visible.

Comment: dystroy, how did you fix it? It's not working for me, and I should add that I'm testing in IE. It's not cell1 I need to change, it's cell3. I know that cell1 will change.

Comment: @triplethreat77 The JSFiddle example by dystroy, and your original code works for me in Chrome. Tested the code in IE10, color renders fine, too.